# What happens when you reference a DOM object (var o=docume...) and that DOM object is removed via parent.innerHTML=''?

Tags: javascript, dom, reference, garbage-collection, innerhtml

Hopefully the title of the question is clear, but:

What happens when the following happens:

```
 <div id="parent">
      <img src="..." id="myImage"/>
 </div>

 <script>
 var i=document.getElementById('myImage');
 document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML='';
 // variable i should not be 'undefined' right? chrome debugger says nope!
 </script>
```

I have tested this in chromes debugger, and it appears that the reference still "lives" on even after the DOM object no longer exists... Am I correct? Doing a console.log(i) (for the above example), still returns the object and all its properties... Shouldnt the garbage collector kick in and 'undefined' this reference since it no longer exists in the DOM?

Does anyone know how something like this is handled across other browsers (more specifically, IE6...) besides chrome?

The reason I am asking is because we globally store some references (depending on user actions), to be used if the user performs another action later on... And we basically need a way to test if the DOM object still exists or not..

I have created a small jsfiddle to make everything clear: http://jsfiddle.net/9HCKt/

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I see now the question wasn't quite clear... How do I test to see if this object still exists in the DOM in a cross browser compatible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle makes things worse :) Why you need to know type of removed element? It will be object before it removed, and after too. If question **what happens**: Your element is `Element`. You can check it with `i instanceof Element`. It's just disconnected from DOM. You actually can connect it again, in other or the same place of DOM and it will be legal. If question **how to check element is connected to DOM**: just check if it's parent defined.

```
if (i.parentElement) {
   // i connected to DOM
} else {
   // i disconnected
};
```

Think about: when you add new element with `document.createElement`, your new element not attached yet. But it obviously not `undefined`.

Comment: Note that this parent element test will not work if it is an ancestor of 'i' which has been disconnected from the DOM ( see http://jsfiddle.net/9HCKt/1/ ). In that case, you will have to go up the hierarchy until you reach the document element.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use jQuery,

`$(document).has($(i)).length`

should be `1` if `i` is still in the DOM, `0` if not.

> Doing a console.log(i) (for the above example), still returns the
>   object and all its properties... Shouldnt the garbage collector kick
>   in and 'undefined' this reference since it no longer exists in the
>   DOM?

In fact, with your `i` variable, you are maintaining a reference to the object, preventing it from being garbage collected.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that by maintaining a reference to the object, garbage collection is prevented... did not know this.